# Why Java wont use GPU?

Tags: java, gpu

I have a java code (game) which runs at 3200 frames per second on my PC. On my laptop, it runs with 100 frames per second, despite the fact they have very similar hardware.

I think the issue might be related to the GPU, since on the laptop it never uses the dedicated GPU.

I know this is a complex question so I will try to give every information regarding this issue.

Originally, the laptop only had 30 FPS, which grow to 50 FPS after changing the preferred GPU in nvidia settings.

After fully disabling the integrated GPU, the FPS went from 50 to 100, still, is nowhere close to the PC.

The PC has around 30% GPU usage when running the game.

The laptop has 0% GPU usage when running the game.

Both machines have the same java version.

I tried it on a second laptop, with 1 integrated GPU and 1 dedicated GPU, it fully behaved like the first laptop. (no GPU usage, low FPS)

I do not understand.

Thank you.

EDIT:

The code below alone lags on the laptops.

````
int xStart = (int) Math.max(0, handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset() / Tile.TILEWIDTH);
    int xEnd = (int) Math.min(width, (handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()
        + handler.getWidth()) / Tile.TILEWIDTH + 1);
    int yStart = (int) Math.max(0, handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset() / Tile.TILEHEIGHT);
    int yEnd = (int) Math.min(height, (handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()
        + handler.getHeight()) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT + 1);


    for(int y = yStart; y < yEnd; y++) {
        for(int x = xStart; x < xEnd; x++) {
            getTile(x, y).render(g, (int) (x * Tile.TILEWIDTH
                - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()),
                (int) (y * Tile.TILEHEIGHT - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()));
        }
    }
```
````

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of how your game code leverages the GPU?

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry i think I misunderstood the question, how can I show you that?

Comment: What does getTile return?

Comment: Tile t = Tile.tiles[tiles[x][y]];
  if(t == null)
   return Tile.grass_full;
  return t;

Comment: And thats the tile object's render method it's nothing special: g.drawImage(texture, x, y, TILEWIDTH, TILEHEIGHT, null);

Comment: Sounds like this Tile type should be included in your question then, since it's the one actually issuing the drawing command. From what we can see here though, you're definitely iterating your map in the wrong order for the way that it's stored (y then x iteration, over x then y storage).

Comment: Yes I just noticed it's the other way around, I fixed it. But this how can this code (and all the other code) run 32 times faster on the PC if they have similar hardware?

Comment: You already asked that in your question above. You don't have to re-ask it in the comments. When someone has an answer for you, they'll post it in the Answers section below.

Comment: Make sure the laptop isn't in a battery saving state